# how to get multiple values using LIKE function

Tags: cognos-10

We have the data abc,xyz,ijk,zya. I cannot use Like In function in Report Studio for multiple values. I am writing Street Name like ('abc'),Street Name like ('xyz'),Street Name like ('ijk'),Street Name like ('zya'). Is there any way i can implement Street Name in ('abc','xyz','ijk','zya'). Any other function we have in Cognos to implement like above. Like In is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to get around this is to explicitly list out each individual search separated with ´or´. For example:

```
[DataItem] like ('abc') or
[DataItem] like ('ijk') or
[DataItem] like ('xyz')
```

If you have the keyword data in an excel spreadsheet starting in A1, you can use the below formula to speed up the process, then just copy and paste it into a filter.

```
="[DataItem] like ('"&A1&"')"
```